# Is the $σ8$ tension in the ΛCDM cosmology evidence that the amount of Dark Matter (DM) in the universe is increasing?

Tags: cosmology, gravity, dark-matter, structure-formation

Strong evidence is provided by recent cosmological studies that “clumpiness” in the large scale structure (LSS), as measured by $σ8$, is decreasing (for example, “Hyper Suprime-Cam Year 3 Results…”, X. Li et al, [arXiv:2304.00702](https://arxiv.org/abs/2304.00702)).
Evidence of the time evolution in LSS starts with the highest inferred value of σ8, that from the CMB. The CMB freezes the beginning of structure formation in time, when clumpiness (arising from BAO, not gravitational disturbance) is most pronounced.
The tension in σ8 arises from observations of structure evolved over cosmological time, i.e. structure observed at lower redshift, which appears less clumpy (lower σ8).
This suggests that ΛCDM might be extended to include anisotropy in the distribution of cold DM, in both the temporal and spatial dimensions. New DM particles could be created by gravitational disturbances (as suggested in a previous question). The DM particles would become concentrated near the source of a disturbance, such as galaxy formation.
As time evolves, the gravitational effect of this new DM becomes more pronounced, and it might act to smooth LSS formation. Observation of LSS at lower redshift captures the result of this time evolved smoothing process as a smaller value of σ8.
The Euclid mission’s 3D maps of LSS may provide further evidence to test this hypothesis. If sample sizes in individual redshift bins are large enough to provide separate estimates of σ8, then an anisotropic DM smoothing model predicts a decreasing trend in this parameter with decreasing redshift.
Would a decrease in clumpiness as LSS evolves be consistent with increasing, localized amounts of cold DM?

Comment: This makes no sense to me. Creating dark matter inside the most overdense regions would make them even denser, boosting the amplitude of clustering further. That's the opposite of smoothing large-scale structure. And anyway you have to make the dark matter out of something else, respecting stress-energy conservation (assuming you are working within general relativity).

Comment: Also, what does "ΛCDM might be extended to include anisotropy in the distribution of cold DM, in both the temporal and spatial dimensions" mean and how does it relate to the rest of the text?

Comment: "Anisotropy" is meant to apply to newly created CDM particles only. Conservation of energy holds in the context of CDM particles entrained in the bulk, viewed as an extra dimensional space-time. Its supporting Hilbert space must be orthogonal to that of the vacuum, precisely because of the constraint of energy conservation. Gravitational waves entrained in the bulk are static, no time elapsing in wave reference frame.